# Ember.js: Get id from currently active route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

Probably the most straight-forward question I've asked recently.

Given a route set up like so:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts', function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'});
    });
});
```

And a URL like so:

```
/accounts/12
```

How would I get the account_id if I wanted to get the currently active account record? The end goal is that I'm doing this:

```
acct = App.Account.find(12)
```

When I'd rather do this

```
acct = App.Account.find(account_id)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the AccountsRoute:

```
Social.AccountsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Social.Account.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the dynamic segment of the current route's path, or how to transition to the route corresponding to a given user (ie. the current user)?

Comment: Can you add your `AccountRoute` class? If you're following guidelines it should have a `params` argument in your `model` function, and you'd be able to retrieve it like `params.account_id` as per [Dynamic Segments guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments)

Comment: add a `params` argument to the `model` function and try the path `params.account_id`

Comment: But I'm accessing that variable from another location. Not, from within the model function. I'm looking for like a "currently active user" method that I can call.

Comment: is this in a repo I can look at or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no canonical mechanism in Ember to store and retrieve the current user. The simplest solution is probably to save your current user's account ID to `Social.currentAccountId` when the user is authenticated (ie. in the success callback of your ajax request). Then you can perform

```
Social.Account.find(Social.get('currentAccountId'))
```

when you need to get the current user.

Comment: Yeah. That's the route I was thinking about going down. Thanks for the suggestion.