# Get the current id of the model when page loads

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build a recently viewed documents list (last 5) within an ember site.

I have the site set up to display a list of links to the documents, and each links through to view a full document. What i am trying to achieve is that when a document is viewed the id of it is added to a recentDoc list. I cannot see how to get the id of the document and i am not sure where i should be trying to get it.

I will put together a jsfiddle shortly

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI I've asked a very similar question:

[Ember.js: Get id from currently active route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164703/ember-js-get-id-from-currently-active-route)

Might be worth your time to check that out.